# R: code runs, but returns "NA" when inspected

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, nodes, na

I created the following node attributes and edge attributes data in R (with  the"statnet" library)

```
mydata <-data.frame(
    
    "source" = c("123","124","123","125","123"),
    "target" = c("126", "123", "125", "122", "111"),
    "color" = c("red","red","green","blue","red"),
    "food" = c("pizza","pizza","cake","pizza","cake")
)

Nodes <-data.frame(
    
    "source" = c("123","124","125","122","111", "126"),
    
    "Country" = c("usa", "uk", "uk", "usa", "uk", "usa"),
    
    "salary" = c("100","150","200","200","100", "100")
    
)

Nodes$salary = as.numeric(Nodes$salary)


net<- as.network(mydata, matrix.type = "edgelist")
set.edge.attribute(net, "color", as.character(mydata$color))
set.edge.attribute(net, "food", as.character(mydata$food))

set.vertex.attribute(net, "Country", as.character(Nodes$Country))
set.vertex.attribute(net, "Salary", as.numeric(Nodes$salary))
```

However, the following line

```
get.vertex.attribute(net, "color")
```

produces:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Have I done something wrong? Or this supposed to be the output?

Thanks

Comment: probably you need the `get.edge.attribute(net, "color")`

Comment: You wrote `set.vertex.attribute(net, "Country", as.character(Nodes$color))`  but the `Nodes` data.frame that you provided does not have a color variable.

Comment: @G5W: sorry about the typo (I have edited the question) I fixed it - but get.vertex.attribute(net, "color") is still returning "NA". Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you just deleted the line of code to set the color. You must _include_ a line of code to set the color.

Comment: I thought I already included a line to set the color? set.edge.attribute(net, "color", as.character(mydata$color))

Comment: could someone please help me out? I am struggling here. thank you

Comment: `get.edge.attribute(net, "color")` for me and returns `[1] "red"   "red"   "green" "blue"  "red" `. In the posted code you are calling `get.` **vertex** `.attribute`.